# POSTGRES generate n rows based on a value n

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to generate a view, in postgres, containing `n` rows based on a value `n` in a column.

Let's make an example. I have a table like this:

```
   A*  |  B   |  C
 --------------------
  abc  |  def |  4
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
```

I need to generate a view made like this:

```
   A  |  B   |  C
------------------------
  abc  |  def |  4
  abc  |  def |  4
  abc  |  def |  4
  abc  |  def |  4
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
  ghi  |  jkl |  7
```

Is there a way to do it smartly? At the moment I am doing N `UNION ALL` with N big enough to cover all the cases (e.g. in this case 7).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `generate_series()`:

```
select t.*, generate_series(1, t.c)
from t ;
```

If you don't want the value in the result set, use a lateral join:

```
select t.*
from t, lateral
     generate_series(1, t.c);
```

Or:

```
select t.*
from t cross join lateral
     generate_series(1, t.c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using *Recursive CTE*

You can try this.

```
WITH RECURSIVE result(A,B,L,C) AS(
    SELECT A,B,1 L,MAX(C) C
   FROM T
    GROUP BY A,B
    UNION ALL
    SELECT A,B,L+1,C
    FROM result
    WHERE L+1 <= C
)
SELECT A,B,C
FROM result
ORDER BY C,A
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/04eb8/11)

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm accepting the other one because it's much more compact

Comment: You are welcome,Gordon‘s solution is better than my :)